# Application with multithreading stopping when trying to save data with Hibernate

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, mariadb, thread-safety

I'm working on a personal project and I have multiple threads that calls the method save in the DAO, the first thread that executes the method works fine but the second one stops while executing the enhanced for in the save method and does not come back. Do I have to make something in the java code/hibernate or is this a configuration of my MariaDB? (Obs: the registers List has around 100 registers which time I save it, I do not know if this has something to do with the amout of data that I have to save).

**The save method on DAO:**

```
`public synchronized void save(List<Registers> registers) throws Exception {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(this.url).openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            for (final Registers register : registers) {
                session.save(register);
            }           

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }`
```

**The Registers class: **

```
`@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "TAB_REGISTERS")
public class Registers implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "COD_REG")
    private Long cod;

    // The rest of the @columns with the mapped variables  and the constructors
}`
```

**My hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>`
```

**The calling code above of the Dao:**

```
public void saveNewRegisters(List<Registers> registers){
        try {
            this.dao.save(registers);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.error("save()", e);
        }
```

}

Comment: Take a thread dump when your program is stuck.

Comment: Are you sure it isn’t throwing an exception? Can we see the calling code?

Comment: @tgdavies I didn't know how to take the thread dump, I've looked up and got this: "Thread-23" #70 [13216] daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=285265.62ms elapsed=983.67s tid=0x000001e63ea547c0 nid=13216 runnable  [0x000000b788cff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at ...

Comment: @TimMoore I put the calling code in the question

Comment: It's worth editing your question and adding the complete thread dump. But first *"the second one stops while executing the enhanced for in the save method and does not come back"* -- what precisely do you observe that leads you to say this?